# Black Screen For Video play url come from server Side

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

1. NSArray *paths =
   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *pathVideo = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyVideo.mp4"];
       NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathVideo];
       self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
       [self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
       [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL.absoluteURL];
       [self.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
       [self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeDefault];
       [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];
       [self.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
        self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 240, 350);
          [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
       [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
       [self.moviePlayer play];

Comment: try to play in device .

Comment: Is the video being streamed from a locale server or from internet? did you check App Transport Security? Apple wants you to use HTTPS. This might be a problem if you are on a local network

Answer (score 1):

> [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view]; add this before

```
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

these line.

FYI. And this player can play in simulator.

Comment: Its Not Working i do that I am changing some code may be help to better understand